# How to convert Bitmap to string without losing quality

Tags: android, bitmap

I've converted an bitmap image into string to save it:

```
............
Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then I retrieve the bitmap from string to set an activity's background just like that:

```
byte[] temp = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp, 0,
                temp.length, options);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Everything works fine but the image quality reduces tremendously. I know it is because `photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);` as I am compressing this image(though in best compressing resolution). So how can I do this without compressing the image? I have also tried the following code but it returns nothing

```
 .......
Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
int bytes = photo.getWidth() * photo.getHeight() * 4;
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
photo.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] b = buffer.array();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Also I am using `sharedPreference` to save the image. I thought of `sqlite` or `internal storage` also, but in both case compressing is needed as I found in internet

Comment: Why are you using a String at all?  You have a byte array-  that's the exact representation.  There's no point in turning it into a string-  send the bytes.  Also, if you want lossless compression, use CompressFormat.PNG

Comment: Thanks for your response :) Changing to `CompressFormat.PNG` increases the quality a little bit but not as same as original image, Also I converted it into `String`because I saved it in sharedPreference. So what can I do for further improvement?

Comment: That's a lot of data for a shared preference.  You'd be better off writing it to a file and passing the filename by shared preference.

Comment: Yes I know, I can do that,But for every case i.e. `sqlite`, `internal storage`, there was `Compression of data` what I've found on net so far. How I can save the bitmap as same as original image without losing quality - whatever sharedPreference, sqlite or internal storage?

Comment: PNG is a lossless format-  there's compression, but no quality loss There is a difference between the two.  PNG is like zip-  its compressed without losing data, there's no difference after re-inflating it.  JPEG is lossy-  it compresses by tossing out some data.  Quality will be lower, but so will the size.  You don't care if there's compression, so long as a lossless algorithm is used.

Comment: yes I understand, Thanks for your effort..BUt I don't know why the image quality seems to be poor after setting it as background of an activity `Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap); getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(d);` :(

Comment: Is it being stretched?  Anything stretched may lose quality.

Comment: My be it is little bit stretched as I open an image from gallery, select it, crop it and set it as background. When cropping, I try to keep it same as to cope with background ratio. May be the crop feature makes it stretched. :(