# How to convert Bitmap to base64 string with keeping quality the same?

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I've tried this code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mylistImg.get(i).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But it lowers the quality a lot. since I want to send a Base64 string to php, I must convert my Bitmap file to string without any quality reduction.
I've read these links but didn't get anything special!

[How to convert Bitmap to string without losing quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746499/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-string-without-losing-quality)

**Edited**
I'm sending **ba1** variable to oracle database as a blob data
but when I see the result in database, the image quality is very low.
and I did not change anything inside my php code about image quality

Comment: Why are you compressing your data?!

Comment: @MaskedMan he is compressing it in 100% quality so there is no actual compressing

Comment: Base64 does not have influence on quality or what ever. Your question is wrong.

Comment: I suggest you remove the compression and try again and let me know if it works.

Comment: Maybe bitmap.compress(...) method does some compression although you give quality = 100  so lets omit that part and try my posted answer below

Comment: `I must convert my Bitmap file to string`. ??? I'm not aware of the existence of Bitmap files. Please explain what you have.

Comment: `I want to send a Base64 string to php`. You still have not told why you would.

Comment: @greenapps I want send blob string to oracle database. i need to orginal image quality and convert that to base64 string

Comment: You did not read all the comments here or what? You only repeat your self and did not answer the questions we had for you. There is nothing in the code you posted that changes quality. Ok? Now try again.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks. but when i see the result, the image quality is very low!

Comment: @greenapps hehe he just removed the accepted mark and he is not making anything clear am pretty sure he needs some guidance and i will flag this post

Comment: My god we know that already. Understand that the code you posted is not the culprit. So what is the cause? That Bitmap that you start with is already bad. But until now you did not show us where that Bitmap came from. You should long have done that meanwhile.

Comment: `but when i see the result, the image quality is very low`. You should also explain where and how you see the result. You should tell us exactly what you are doing.

Comment: PNG compression is lossless. Therefore, you should not see any degradation of quality. BTW: quality is ignored for PNG compression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i just changed the way we get the byte array rather than using `.compress` method

```
//b is the Bitmap
Bitmap b=mylistImg.get(i);
//calculate how many bytes our image consists of.
int bytes = b.getByteCount();
//or we can calculate bytes this way. Use a different value than 4 if you don't use 32bit images.
//int bytes = b.getWidth()*b.getHeight()*4; 

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

byte[] ba= buffer.array();

ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that compress method. Moreover you now create data that the server cannot handle. This makes things worse. OP has misinformed us as there is nothing in the code he posted that lowers the quality.

Comment: So i am pretty surprised that suddenly this answer is marked as correct.

Comment: @greenapps I made an assumption that compress method does some compression even if quality is 100 and it seems that my assumption was right.
But what i didn't understand is what is the data that created that the server cannot handle now? we are always sending a String disregarding the way we produce that String.
I think this worked for OP as it is marked as accepted.

Comment: Yes you are sending a base64 encoded string. But the server could decode that string and then save the bytes to file. With the compress method there would be a nice png file on the server as result. But with your code it would be an invalid image file.

Comment: i dont think so OP has tried this method and when he sent the image to server he decoded it on the server side and looked at it that it didn't loose quality and its valid image file. or how did he managed to test it if it do produce invalid image file?

Comment: Good questions. But dont assume anything. We can talk about it until tomorrow and still know nothing. OP should tell us what he is doing of course. I wonder why he is so silent.

Comment: Yes you are right we need him to tell us. He seems to be new on Stack Overflow his account is created today.